# A value problem on continuous function

Tags: continuity

Let $f\colon[1,8]\to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that  $f(1)=4$ and $f(8)=3$.

Show that exists $x_0 \in [1,8]$ such that $$f(x_0)= \sqrt[3]{x_0}+x_0.$$

How can I start this?

Comment: Set $g(x):= f(x) - x^{1/3} - x$.  Consider what happens if you substitute in $x=1$ and $x=8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - \sqrt[3]x - x$ and notice that $g$ is also continuous in $[1,8]$.

Further notice that $g(1) = 4 -1 -1 = 2$ and $g(8) = 3 - 2 - 8 = -7 $. In particular,
$ \ g(1) > 0 > g(8)$.

Then, by the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), there is $x_0 \in ]0,8[$  such that $g(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much I get it

Comment: You're welcome. In these kind of problems where you have to find a value which satisfies some condition, you usually define an auxiliary function and apply the intermediate value theorem.